# Why localstorage is not working firefox 57 and Vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, firefox, vue.js

I want to change the language by click in the language name , i am using vuex-i18n for set the language in the front end. and i am using localStorage but the localStorage is not working in firefox , i am testing in Firefox 57 , i test in Chrome and Edge and is working there but not in firefox.(I already check in the config and dom.storage.enabled is true)
My component code is :

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand"  id="menu-toggle" @click ="OpenMenu(menuclicked)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="" @click="setLanguage('en')" >English</a></li>
                <li><a href="" @click="setLanguage('es')"> Spanish</a></li>

                <li v-for ="item in topNavbarOptions"><router-link v-on:click.native="item.clickEvent" :to="{name:item.route}"><span :class="item.icon"></span> {{ item.name}}</router-link></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>
<script>  
import  'vue-awesome/icons';
import {HTTP} from '../common/http-common';  
export default {
    props:['topNavbarOptions'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            menuclicked: false

        }
    },
    created:function(){
       this.$i18n.set(localStorage.getItem("locale"));
    },
    methods: {
        OpenMenu: function (menuclicked) {
            this.menuclicked = !menuclicked;
            this.$emit('openmenu', this.menuclicked );
        },
        setLanguage:function(locale)
       {
          HTTP.get('lang/'+locale)
          .then(response =>{
              //Set locale from backend
            localStorage.setItem("locale", locale);

          })
          .catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
          });

        }



    }

}
</script>
```

i am usign axios in  my HTTP call.There is a way to set the language without using localstorage or sessionstorage?. what i have to change in my code to make compatible with Firefox?.

Thank you.

Comment: `localStorage` works fine in Firefox.  Use a debugger to see what isn't working.

Comment: localStorage is from browser, there is no relation with vue.

Comment: Did you debug to see where it is failing. Is it writing it? Are you able to retrieve it?

Comment: You are asking localStorage for locale key in created() method. Are you sure this key exists in that that moment? If not, access it this way `localStorage['locale'] || 'en' `. This will not generate an error.

Comment: Yes in the create() method is empty ..but if i click the language i access the method setLanguage(), if i check in the devtools in chrome localStorage is set to the language ,but if i click and in Firefox LocalStorage is empty , is never set. The same test works in Edge.

Comment: I get a javascript exception: NS_ERROR_FILE_NO_DEVICE_SPACE when I try any of localStorage.getItem(), localStorage.setItem()  functions. FF version is 57.0 (Quantum). I still try to find the cause. btw: same function works just fine in chrome... So it IS a firefox problem. Looks like FF lost its localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `window.localStorage`? This should be context- and scope-unreliant.

Comment: it works but just in chrome , if i call the window.localStorage inside the response is empty in firefox.  HTTP.get('lang/'+localecode)
          .then(response =>{
            window.localStorage.setItem('lang', response.data.locale);
          })
          .catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
          });

Answer (score 0):

try to

1. delete the local storage for this site in settings. URL=about:preferences#privacy
2. close FF
3. restart FF

it worked in my case - I had updated to version 57 - somehow my profile got corrupted
in Windows the FF profile is located at:
C:\Users[youraccountname]\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

Comment: Thank you , i already try it, but it does not work. I test in Windows and Ubuntu and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my code to solve the problem . The problem is when the LocalStorage is inside of an axios http response (setLanguage method) It works in Chrome but in firefox LocalStorage is empty. when i move the LocalStorage outside the response it works.

```
<script>  
import  'vue-awesome/icons';
import {HTTP} from '../common/http-common';  
export default {
    props:['topNavbarOptions'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            menuclicked: false,
            locale:'en'

        }
    },
    mounted:function(){

      if(localStorage.getItem("locale"))
        {
          this.locale = localStorage.getItem("locale");
        }
           this.$i18n.set(this.locale);

   },
    methods: {
        OpenMenu: function (menuclicked) {
            this.menuclicked = !menuclicked;
            this.$emit('openmenu', this.menuclicked );
        },
        setLanguage:function(localecode)
       {  
          //Set front end locale
         localStorage.setItem("locale",localecode); 
          //Set backend locale
          HTTP.get('lang/'+localecode)
          .then(response =>{

          })
          .catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
          });

        }



    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

*browser.storage.local.get()* - to retrive data
*browser.storage.local.set()* - to post data

Comment: How can i use this for all browsers? do you have an example?

Comment: The above is only accepted for Firefox. For Chrome, just replace `browser` with `chrome`. Such queries are generally done from a web extension based on these browsers. In case you wanna do it from your server, try using cookies as they are easy to maintain.

Comment: I use vue-cookie but te result is the same, it works only in chrome , i think could be something with axios,